# Set two alarm and handle them differently - UNIX/C

Tags: c, unix, alarm, sigterm

I need to set two alarm(). The first one to kill one process, the second one to kill all the processes I got. Obviously the first alarm is smaller than the second one. How can I handle the two SIGALRM (and then the SIGTERM) in order to make these things? I mean, is possible to handle differently the same signal from two different alarm()?

Comment: Are you saying that the first time you get a SIGALARM you want to perform one actin, and the second time you get a SIGALARM you do something else?  If so, use a global variable to track it.

Comment: When you use `alarm()`, the OS only keeps track of a single alarm for you. If you need two alarms, for M and N seconds from now, you'll have to arrange to set ehe second one (for N-M seconds) as or after the first one fires.  You might want to set up a genersl piece of alarm management code for this.

Comment: Or you might be able to use `timer_create()`, which does let you create multile timers all running at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is possible, with timer_create to set a timer which start again at the end after it performed an action, and a second (longer) timer which perform another action at the end? Hope I explained well what I want to do

Comment: @palnic I think so.  To be sure I would have to check the documentation of `timer_create` -- which you can do, too!  Just do a web search.